# Deserialization error: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I'm having an issue serializing and deserializing a custom object that I have created. I'm not too sure why the error is occurring, I don't see anything in my code that could be directly causing this issue. I've tested it without having the interface inherited, and it still throws the error.

Interface:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void LoadTest(string id, string className, string classMethod, bool isNegative, List<string> args, string expectedReturn);

    string GetId();
    string GetClassName();
    string GetMethod();
    List<string> GetArgs();
    string GetExpectedReturn();
    bool IsNegative();

    bool HasRan();
    void RunTest(...);

    string GetTestReturn();
    bool GetTestResult();
}
```

Class that has issues being serialized:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestXML : ITest
{
    private string _id;
    private string _className;
    private string _classMethod;
    private bool _isNegative;
    private List<string> _args;
    private string _expectedReturn;

    private bool _hasRan;

    private string _actualReturn;

    private bool _passOrFail;

    public static string ServerEncodeStatic(TestXML test)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(ms);

        formatter.Serialize(ms, test);

        ms.Position = 0;

        //TestXML t = (TestXML)formatter.Deserialize(ms); // ERROR occurs here as well if this is uncommented

        var toret = sr.ReadToEnd();

        return toret;
    }

    public static TestXML ServerDecodeStatic(string data)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
            {
                sw.Write(data);
                sw.Flush();

                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                TestXML t = (TestXML)formatter.Deserialize(ms); // ERROR occurs here

                return (TestXML)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
            }
        }
    }

    public void LoadTest(string id, string className, string classMethod, bool isNegative, List<string> args, string expectedReturn)
    {
        _id = id;
        _className = className;
        _classMethod = classMethod;
        _isNegative = isNegative;
        _args = args;
        _expectedReturn = expectedReturn;
    }


    public string GetId()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public string GetClassName()
    {
        return _className;
    }

    public string GetMethod()
    {
        return _classMethod;
    }

    public List<string> GetArgs()
    {
        return _args;
    }

    public string GetExpectedReturn()
    {
        return _expectedReturn;
    }

    public bool IsNegative()
    {
        return _isNegative;
    }


    public bool HasRan()
    {
        return _hasRan;
    }

    public void RunTest(...)
    {
        ...
    }


    public string GetTestReturn()
    {
        return _actualReturn;
    }

    public bool GetTestResult()
    {
        return _passOrFail;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I have rewrote the two functions as such, and they are now working!:

```
    public static string ServerEncodeStatic(TestXML test)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        formatter.Serialize(ms, test);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }

    public static TestXML ServerDecodeStatic(string data)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(data));

        var toret = (TestXML)formatter.Deserialize(ms);

        return toret;
    }
```

Comment: You cant just treat the output as string; if it contains a NUL (Chr(0)) the string will get truncated at that point.  Use `Convert.ToBase64String()` instead of the streamreader

Comment: Would I want to use that on the streamreader? There's no way to get the string out of the MemoryStream without using a StreamReader right?

Comment: `Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())`

Comment: Okay, so I still can't get it to convert back. I updated the sw.write to: sw.Write(Convert.FromBase64String(data));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant just treat the output as string; if it contains a NUL (Chr(0)) the string will get truncated at that point. Use `Convert.ToBase64String()` instead of `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.  Those are for text which is not what you are working with.

```
formatter.Serialize(ms, test);
return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
```

To initialize the memstream for deserializing:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(b64str))
    ...
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I have a feeling I could even port this code out to a templated solution as well.